listen to change to the url using html.window.history.pushState in a flutter web app
is there a way to listen to url changes made like this or so in a flutter web app::
html.window.history.pushState(null, '', "url");

this is the closest stackoverflow i could find but it didnt help::
How to watch for changes in window.location with Dart?
chatgpt/claude is not helping.
thanks in advance

Well using some sort state management technique, you can definitely  keep the state in check. But again, brother. My suggestion is, try not to make a website using Flutter. It will be really hard to achieve something that way. But if you really have to do it. Use GoRouter for routing. It's never a great idea to reinvent the wheel. But if you're experimenting. Feel free to check out some state management system. And keep a check on the html.window.history.state. And you can easily follow the changes. Good luck!
